# Exercise on heads or tails: Random class

Tags: java, random

I made a very simple random generator on heads or tails.
When playing 100 times, the result always fluctuates around a relation of 60/40 at max. In other words: I never get a result of let's say 35 - 65, or even 25 - 75.
What I find a bit remarkable is that I relatively often get a result of 50/50.
What is the reason for this?

Here is my main class (method named "play"):

```
package headsOrTails;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        HeadsOrTails headsOrTails = new HeadsOrTails(100); 
        headsOrTails.play(); 

        System.out.println(headsOrTails.getTotalHeads()); 
        System.out.println(headsOrTails.getTotalTails()); 
    } 

}
```

My HeadsOrTails class where the random number gets generated:

```
package headsOrTails;

import java.util.Random;

public class HeadsOrTails {

    private int nrOfThrows; 
    private int totalTails; //0 
    private int totalHeads;  //1 

    //Constructor 
    public HeadsOrTails(int nrOfThrows){ 
        this.nrOfThrows = nrOfThrows; 
    } 

    public int getTotalTails(){
        return this.totalTails; 
    } 

    public int getTotalHeads(){ 
        return this.totalHeads; 
    } 

    public void play(){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < this.nrOfThrows; i++) {
            Random random = new Random(); 
            int rnd = random.nextInt(2); 

            if(rnd == 0){ 
                this.totalTails++; 
            } else { 
                this.totalHeads++; 
            }
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: You should really take a look at what [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) is.

Comment: Since the majority of the people aren't Dutch, I'd say it would make more sense to replace the variable and method names with English ones.

Comment: "What I find a bit remarkable is that I relatively often get a result of 50/50." please explain what you expected and why you find this remarkable. Isn't it the objective of a random number generator to be fair (if not instructed otherwise)? Unless you mean that you are amazed with how well it works..

Comment: Look: if you draw it only once, you'll get 100% of the draws on the same value. Isn't that even more remarkable?

Comment: I was doubting if my method worked correctly, but I see now that the more you play, the more likely you get to 50. Never learned much about probability, I'll look into it.

Comment: Observations are in-line with expectations. Did you see any issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is because of the probability distribution of a coin toss. If you decrease your tossingloop you will realise that the distribution is getting away from 50/50 but if you increase your iterations to lets say 10000 you will probably get a pretty close to 50/50 distribution. Check Law of Large Numbers. 
Its a mathematical law and not dependent on the classes you write.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public class Rnd {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    int nrOfThrows = 100;
    int[] diffNr = new int[nrOfThrows];

    int plays = 1000;
    for(int i=0; i<plays; i++) {
        diffNr[play(nrOfThrows)]++;
    }
    System.out.println (Arrays.toString (diffNr));
}

static int play(final int nr) {
    int heads = 0;
    int tails = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
        Random random = new Random ();
        int rnd = random.nextInt (2);

        if (rnd == 0) {
            heads++;
        } else {
            tails++;
        }
    }

    return Math.abs (heads-tails);
}
}
```

It'll play your game a thousand times, and count how often a certain difference between heads and tails is achieved. Sample output:

```
[68, 0, 179, 0, 130, 0, 127, 0, 127, 0, 99, 0, 85, 0, 45, 0, 46, 0, 37, 0, 28, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... only zeros from here]
```

This is more or less what you would expect.. you quite often see no difference, then 179/2 = ~90 times a difference of one, and the bigger the difference, the less likely it is.

As others already said, take a look into probability to understand why you would expect this ;-)

Comment: Interesting test, quite new for me. I'll look more into probability. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Random class is supposed to behave like this. The values should be equally distributed between all possible results. In your case 0 and 1.
You get more fluctuates the less you try. So then you should reduce the repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not an expert in random numbers but the javadoc states that
`Random.nextInt(int)` generates a uniformly distributed integer. 
So with a sufficiently large number of tries one would expect the result to be close to 50/50. In other words with `Random.nextInt(2)` you are just as likely to see a 0 as you are likely to see a 1.

Answer (score 1):

You're summing up 100 independent coin tosses, each with equal probability of yielding heads or tails.  In probability this is the exact definition of a binomial distribution with n=100 and p=0.5, described as `k ~ Binomial(100, 0.5)`.  The probability that `k` is between any specified pair of numbers can be calculated exactly to within floating point limitations:

```
P{40 <= k <= 60} = 0.9647997998
P{35 <= k <= 65} = 0.9982100696
P{30 <= k <= 70} = 0.999967840
P{25 <= k <= 75} = 0.999999819
```

If you ran your program 100 times you could expect to see a small number (perhaps 2, 3, or 4) of cases where you got an outcome outside the 40-60 range, and would be unlikely to see results outside the larger ranges unless you ran a lot more experiments.  Expect only a couple of extremes outside the range 25-75 out of tens of millions of repetitions of 100 coin tosses.

In other words, you appear to be getting exactly what the math predicts—it's rare to get values outside the 40-60 range, and progressively rarer to get wider disparities.

This result is at the core of statistical hypothesis testing.  If you observe outcomes that would be extremely rare under the assumption (hypothesis) you're dealing with a fair coin, then you reject that assumption and conclude that it's not a fair coin.  There's always some chance that it really is a fair coin and that you got one of the rare events, but you can choose how much risk you're willing to tolerate by choosing the threshold for how extreme a result has to be before you reject the hypothesis.